# Perform unwind segue SWIFT5

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, unwind-segue

I have three viewControllers. First one news list , second Login screen and third is about reading article.
If the news is not free I redirect the user to login screen. If user successuly logged in then I'm showing the selected news. But the problem is when user hit back button it return to login screen so I use unwind segue to direct home screen. When I use unwind segue it was working good but one problem is my login screen is still seen about 1 second.
So is there a way to hide viewcontroller or make much faster

I detect If the navigation bar back button is clicked.

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    if self.isMovingFromParent {

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHomeScreen", sender: self)


        }
}
```

then I perform unwind segue.

Comment: Try calling `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` instead of performing segue when back bar button is selected.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes it works too but still seen secon viewcontroller about 1 second

Comment: Then maybe you could try this: After the successful log in, you should present the selected news using `navigationController?.setViewControllers([newsListController, articleController], animated: true)`. You probably have the references to those 2 view controllers, so just use this method to present them.